# Xcode Cocoapods lib.a libraries show red when move to other mac try removed the lib and re-archive but no luck

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I tried to build the same code with my other mac at work.

My home MAC is OS X El-captain with Xcode 7.3.1 (Intel 2.3G) but my work runs on Xcode 7.2.1 Mac Air 11" 2011 build (Intel i5 1.6G)

I am not sure what's wrong but the compiler complains with segmentation fault 11.

I tried to delete the lib in red and clean and rebuild, no luck, so please help.

I ran cocoapods to install Firebase Admob.

Here is the screen shot of the build settings

[image: screen shot of the build settings]

Comment: Try re-adding the libraries.

Comment: Also, please notice that for the Release configuraiton you should not have Build Active Architecture Only set tot YES.

Answer (score 0):

install `cocoapods` again for that project so that all dependencies will renew again.

Comment: Did that but no luck